# Simulation basic error, Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have an error, I don't understand why.
So if I enter:

> proj:calc([{push,{num,2}},{push,{num,3}},{plus},{push,{num,4}},{mul}]).

While the code:

```
calc(List) -> 
[Res] = lists:foldl(fun calc/2, [], List),
Res.

calc({plus}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 + N2 | Stack];
calc({mul}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 * N2 | Stack];
calc({push,{num,X}}, Stack) -> [X | Stack].
```

I get an output of 20 (perfect just what I want).

But if I have an input like this:

> proj:calc([{push,{num,2}},{push,{num,3}},{plus},{pop},{ret},{push,{num,4}},{mul},{pop},{ret}]).

While the code:

```
calc(List) -> 
[Res] = lists:foldl(fun calc/2, [], List),
Res.

calc({plus},{pop},{ret}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 + N2 | Stack];
calc({mul},{pop},{ret}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 * N2 | Stack];
calc({push,{num,X}}, Stack) -> [X | Stack].
```

I get an error:

> exception error: no function clause matching proj:calc({pop},[5])

I am new to er lang, so why is this happening and how do I resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration of a fold, map or filter only consumes one element of a list. Here you have three elements that represent a single operation: `{plus},{pop},{ret}`. You either have to wrap that in a single tuple `{{plus},{pop},{ret}}` or remember that stack machines *implicitly perform* `{pop}` and `{ret}` at the end of every operation already -- so these two operations can be dropped.

With that in mind, your code should read the first way, or like this:

```
calc({{plus},{pop},{ret}}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 + N2 | Stack];
calc({{mul},{pop},{ret}}, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 * N2 | Stack];
calc({push,{num,X}}, Stack) -> [X | Stack].
```

And your input should be:

```
[{push,{num,2}},{push,{num,3}},{{plus},{pop},{ret}},{push,{num,4}},{{mul},{pop},{ret}}]
```

A function passed to a map function must be arity 2, and here you had mixed two clauses of arity 4 and one clause of arity 2 in the same function definition -- which is not legal to begin with.

In any case, the series you are describing is inherent to a stack machine already, and does not need to be spelled out. This is why your implementation is consistently more complex looking/problematic than most examples.

Comment: thanks, I knew it would not work when I tried everything. I also attempted to use filters but I don't know how to implement it correctly or it would just not work.

Comment: A filter filters things out according to the outcome of a test, leaving the remainder of the list. A map transforms a list by applying one operation to every member of the list. What you are trying to do is crunch all the values of a list into a single value, and that is what a fold does: it folds everything up into a single value at the end (an aggregate operation). It just happens to be possible to define every action of a stack machine as a single function, and because folds already do the "pop, operate, push, iterate" steps by their nature, it is easy to build a stack machine with a fold.

Comment: Either that or have separate clauses in `calc/2` for `{plus}`, `{mul}`, `{pop}` and `{ret}`. Note that there is no need to have these instructions as tuples, they could just as well be `plus`, `mul`, `pop` and `ret`.